VBA checkBoxes being inserted differently after running code again
I am trying to insert UserForm CheckBoxes in column C of my Excel file because I'll use logic in another macro to see if they are checked and write information to Word based on that. This code worked the first maybe 50 times I ran it and suddenly today it doesn't work even though I didn't change anything.
This is what I get:

This is the code I am using:
Sub InsertCheckBoxes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim cbHeight As Double
    Dim cbWidth As Double
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to insert checkboxes
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  
    
    ' Define the range where checkboxes will be inserted
    Set rng = ws.Range("C34:C59")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the range and insert checkboxes
    For Each cell In rng
        ' Add a checkbox for each cell
        Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
        
        ' Pre-check the checkbox and set the linked cell to TRUE
        cb.Value = xlOn
        
        ' Link the checkbox to cell D corresponding to the current row
        With cb
            .LinkedCell = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Address
            .Caption = ""
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            
            ' Retrieve the actual dimensions of the checkbox
            cbHeight = .Height
            cbWidth = .Width
            
            ' Center the checkbox horizontally and vertically
            .Left = cell.Left + (cell.Width - cbWidth) / 2
            .Top = cell.Top + (cell.Height - cbHeight) / 2
        End With
        
        ' Set the corresponding cell in column D to TRUE
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = True
    Next cell
End Sub

The difference is that now the CheckBoxes are not centered and sometimes they overlap over lines or into the next cell down. Originally, they used to be perfectly centered. Although my rows are uneven in size, I've tried on a smaller Worksheet with even row sizes, and it still doesn't work. The weird thing is that it was literally working 2 days ago. Can someone help me figure out why? I'm also open to using Python to read the file and insert the CheckBoxes if Python can allow me to do that.

I think your maths may be off cause, you are setting the size to the cell height and width, then adding (cell.height-cbHeight)/2 so you are saying (100-100)/2)  Would it be easier to set the left and top at creation?

Your code works perfectly for me. Can't recreate the issue.
